# how to select the maximum current value from table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT
    credit_detail.bill_id,
    credit_detail.credit_id
    FROM credit_detail
   WHERE credit_detail.credit_id=(SELECT max(credit_id)FROM credit_detail )
```

Input:

```
bill_id credit_id
 2 4 
 6 8 
 2 17 
 6 12
```

expected

```
Bill_id credit_id 
 2 17 
 6 12
```

Comment: maximum current value of what? Give us some sample data and expected output. What does the query (which is the only thing in the question) gives you?

Comment: bill id     credit id 
 2           4
 6           8
 2           17
 6           12


expeted 

Bill id     credit id
  2          17
  6          12

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read the [tour] and [ask] first.

Comment: @ritesh in the question please

Comment: @riteshsaswadkar edit your question, don't add info with comments

Comment: You need MAX and GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `group by` on bill_id for maximum credit_id like this:

```
select 
  bill_id,
  max(credit_id) credit_id
from credit_details
group by bill_id
```

If you have more columns in the credit_details to fetch for the max credit_id, use this:

```
select c1.*
credit_details c1 inner join (
    select bill_id, max(credit_id) credit_id
    from credit_details
    group by bill_id
) c2 on c1.bill_id = c2.bill_id
    and c1.credit_id = c2.credit_id;
```